# Django class variable to instance variable

Tags: python, django

It seems like name and tagline would be class variables, how have they managed to define name and tagline as instance variables. Creating an instance of blog would be like Blog(name='...', tagline='...'). Wouldnt the variable be available like so, Blog.name and Blog.tagline

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but any field defined in the model will be accessible.
For example, suppose that somewhere in the program, the created samples are to be categorized based on tagline, in which case the corresponding field will be the classification criterion.
But about `__str__` function, this is what Python and Django use whenever a model instance needs to be forced and displayed as a simple string, and you can put any field you need in it ([see here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.__str__)).

Comment: Im asking, are the class variables name and tagline instantiated using keyword arguments in the base class constructor?